# Ruby / Watir-Webdriver - Cannot access the file after downloading it

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am working on a tests scenario that downloads a file from a website and adds it to folder.
For the download part, I am using the code described on the [browser-downloads](http://watir.github.io/docs/browser-downloads/) page within the Watir documentation. 
The main problem was encountered in my tests when I am waiting for the file to be downloaded:

```
    def verify_csv_file_exists
     path = Dir.getwd + "/downloads/"
     until File.exist?("#{path}*.csv") == true
      sleep 1
     end 
    end
```

When running the tests, the procedure above never stops, because it cannot see the file in the directory, although the file is downloaded.

Does anyone know a way how I can handle this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply check the directory contents **before** you download the file, then wait until there's a new file added to the directory (by comparing the current content with the previous content). This is how you get the new file name:

This should do the job:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

file_name = nil
download_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads"
download_directory.gsub!("/", "\\") if Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.windows?
downloads_before = Dir.entries download_directory

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2 # custom location
profile['browser.download.dir'] = download_directory
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "text/csv,application/pdf"

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile

b.goto 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18859962/hello.csv'

30.times do
  difference = Dir.entries(download_directory) - downloads_before
  if difference.size == 1
    file_name = difference.first 
    break
  end  
  sleep 1
end
raise "Could not locate a new file in the directory '#{download_directory}' within 30 seconds" if not file_name
puts file_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alister. Your solution does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "glob" with `File.exists?` like `File.exists?("*.csv")`. It checks whether the file named `*.csv` exists, not any file with name ends with `.csv`. You should use exact file name to check if a file exists.

Comment: The problem is that the name of the file contains an unique number, that is generated when pressing the Download link. There is now way I can get this number :|, so I used this method, to see if the files is present in the folder.

Comment: What I mean is, if the file isn't there, then an infinite sleep loop won't help much.

Comment: The file is there, is downloaded... but, is not visible by ruby during the test run. Even if I run the code to display all the files from the directory (after the download is done), it returns nothing-> path = Dir.getwd + "/downloads/"
      Dir.glob("#{path}*.csv").each { |f| puts f }

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this instead:

```
Dir.glob('downloads/*.csv').any?
```

Also how is sleeping for 1 second supposed to change anything? Is this a multithreaded app?

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. I tried almost all methods. It seems that the files downloaded while the test run cannot be accessed.

Comment: Or, more exactly, the files downloaded during the tests are not visible.